# Can we store data in global variable in where block in Spock framework?

Tags: groovy, spock

I am trying to store data in where block .Have parameter(SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS) and try to fill data which will be global variable that i will use later for other tests .Static variables are declared .Is is possible to fill data in WHERE block with assignment in when block?
APIV2 is call from which i want to fill data in SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS
I tried also to declare SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS as static and in @Shared part
this is declared as static
static String APIV2
static String Obos
static String Arendal
static String Sparebank
static String Andebu
in When block is :

SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS = APIV2

and in WHERE block:

```
        SUBSCRIBER_ID         | SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS          
        subscriberIdObos      | Obos                 
        subscriberIdArendal   | Arendal              
        subscriberIdSparebank | Sparebank            
        subscriberIdAndebu    | Andebu
```

I tried to declare SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS as static and @Shared but its the same

Answer (score 2):

Here's my advice.  Don't do this.  You are creating a dependency between tests that is going to make your test brittle, and difficult to work with.  For one it means Test B can't work without Test A running, and it also means order is important because Test A has to run before Test B to setup the "global variable".  You won't have test isolation so people who try to run Test B are going not understand the relationship between the tests and you'll forever be explaining how to run the tests when developers are working.

What's better is you create either a `setup()` and `cleanup()` methods or `setupSpec()` and `cleanupSpec()` methods.  `setup()/cleanup()` will be before each test method while `setupSpec()/cleanupSpec()` will be run before and after the Specification is run (ie all test methods).

So doing this and putting these in a base class can enable you to share those setup methods to cleanly separate your tests from each other while sharing the code to do so.

```
class AbstractSubscriberDetailsSetup {
    void setupSpec() {
    }

    void cleanupSpec() {
    }
}

class SomeSubscriberDetailsSpec extends SubscriberDetailSetup {

    def testSubscriberDetails() {
    }
}
```

If you want to save state into an instance variable in `SubscribeDetailSetup` that is perfectly fine to do because it's not global.  And if another spec subclasses SubscriberDetailSetup they'll be isolated from that state (because it's not global!), and everything will work independently but share that setup code.  Not the data.

Comment: I am amazed that you were able to answer the question, and the answer was even accepted. IMO, the question asked is almost incomprehensible. I read it 3x, but could not understand what exactly the OP wants. I also could not detect a connection between the question and this answer. While everything you say is correct, how is it related to the question? Maybe I am just too stupid to get it.

Comment: @kriegaex it was the "global variable" desire that I zeroed in on.  The rest of the question was mere details about what they might want to store in that global variable.  I understood it had something to do with Subscriber details which I get he wants to insert something into a DB and do that 1 time.  But the details all hinged on global variables which is a huge mistake so I just tried to show him an alternative to global variables and the mess they create for any project.  The rest of it he can figure out. ;-)

Comment: @chubbsondubs Thanks you.I could not expose all data because of company but seems to me you got the point and offered alternative way.Anyway this is working if i put with IF (SUBSCRIBER_ID==subscriberIdObos){SUBSCRIBER_DETAILS=Obos},but they want me to find another way which is not easy

Comment: _"I could not expose all data because of company"_ Dear Jadran, as a newbie, you are very welcome here, like everyone else. There are no stupid questions, but better or worse ones. Your statement I just quoted is, however, unworthy of anyone calling himself a software developer, because it is just a lame excuse for laziness. Nobody expects you to ever share classified original code. Instead, a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem is enough. Snippets out of context are not. You were just lucky someone made the right guess.